# Mathematica: Transparent background with PNG

Tags: image, wolfram-mathematica, plot, mathematica-8

This is most likely a bug in Mathematica 8.0.1 and maybe other versions too. Lets try the following:

```
Table[
 Export[
  "Res_" <> ToString[r] <> ".png", Rasterize[
  Style[x^2 + y^2, 40],
  Background -> None,
  ImageResolution -> r
 ],
 Background -> None],
 {r, {20, 40, 100, 300, 400, 500, 600}}
]
```

This is a screen shot of what I obtain:

[image: Output]

First thing to notice is that the last two pictures are the wrong size. This is fine to some extent since I'm satisfied with a resolution of 300 or above. Now look at this:

```
in = 72;
G3D = Graphics3D[AspectRatio -> 0.925, Axes -> {True, True, True}, 
  AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}}, AxesStyle -> Directive[10, Black],
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 12}, Boxed -> False,
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black], 
  ImagePadding -> All, ImageSize -> 5 in, PlotRange -> All,
  PlotRangePadding -> None, TicksStyle -> Directive[10], 
  ViewPoint -> {2, -2, 2}, ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, Background -> None
];
surf = Show[
  Graphics3D[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1], Background -> None, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}], Options[G3D]
];
fig = Show[surf, AxesStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0]], 
  Background -> None
];
```

I wish to `Export` fig as a png file with transparent background with a high resolution. Here goes my lame attempt with the always buggy Mathematica.

```
Table[
  Export[
    "Res_" <> ToString[r] <> ".png",
    Rasterize[fig, ImageResolution -> r, Background -> None],
    Background -> None
  ], {r, {20, 40, 100, 300, 400, 500}}
]
```

Here is a screenshow of a few png files.

[image: Images]

All of them came out with the expected resolution :). But what happened to my transparent background? I have specified many times through my code `Background -> None` and yet this doesn't want to work. I looked around the web and I found this:

http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Feb/msg00943.html

Lets use this idea.

```
bgImage = Image[ConstantArray[{0, 0, 0, 0}, Reverse[ImageDimensions[fig]]], 
  ColorSpace -> "RGB"];
compImage = ImageCompose[bgImage, fig];
Table[Export["Res_" <> ToString[r] <> ".png", 
  Rasterize[compImage, ImageResolution -> r, Background -> None], 
  Background -> None], {r, {20, 40, 100, 300, 400, 500}}]
```

[image: Images]

No backgrounds!!! :) Great. But what happened to the sizes of my images? The resolution is increasing but the image size started to decrease. I have really been messing around with this problem for too long now. I hope one of you can shed some light into this Mathematica bug and can find a hack in order to achieve a transparent background PNG with high resolution. Please mention the Mathematica version you guys are using if you find an answer.

Comment: Just a quick comment. I worked with transparent bkg only a few times, but always did that in the RGBA channel representation.

Comment: On version 7, the `x^2 + y^2` graphic renders correctly, and the first set of spheres is exported with transparency.  Therefore, I have added the mathematica-8 tag.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Do you mean version 7.0.0? I tried the `x^2 + y^2` in version 7.0.1 and Res_400.png appears the same as Res_500.png and Res_600.png. Thank you for adding the tag.

Comment: @belisarius, What do you mean by RGBA channel representation? I checked `ColorSpace` and the allowed values are "Grayscale", "RGB", "CMYK" and "HSB".

Comment: See my answer below for the output I get.

Comment: @jmlopez RGBA is normal RGB with the alpha channel added. Try `Graphics3D[{RGBColor[0, 1, 0, .3], Sphere[]}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all: do not use `ImageResolution` when exporting! This buggy options is useless most of the time and does not do what one can expect. It works as an analog of `ImageSize`.

Instead, use `Magnify` command and `Magnification` option of `Style`. They do what we want to get from `ImageResolution`!

Now about the reason for the behavior showed in the first part of the question. Yes, it happens. And yes, it is machine-dependent. Is it a bug? Yes, at least a great imperfection. It it completely unexpected? As for me - not.

It seems that the source of the problem is that rendering of graphics is in really made by the FrontEnd and the latter uses default settings for `Cell` when converting graphics to raster.

```
In[1]:= Options[Cell, PageWidth]
Out[1]= {PageWidth -> WindowWidth}
```

Lets try to see how output of

```
Table[Rasterize[Style[x^2 + y^2, 40], Background -> None, 
  ImageResolution -> r], {r, {300, 400, 500, 600}}]
```

looks at different **run-time** sizes of the notebook window:

[image]

One can see the obvious dependence of the output on the notebook window size.

A workaround is to pass `PageWidth` directly to `Cell`:

```
Rasterize[
 Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@Style[x^2 + y^2, 40], PageWidth -> Infinity], 
 ImageResolution -> 600]
```

[image]

---

P.S. In addition. The only case I know when `ImageResolution` works as expected is PDF export with `"AllowRasterization"->True`:

```
First@ImportString[
  ExportString[Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}], "PDF", 
   "AllowRasterization" -> True, ImageResolution -> 200], "PDF"]
```

But it does not allow to specify transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of tracking down the extent of the error, here are the images I get from Mathematica 7.0.1 on Windows XP

```
Table[Export["Res_" <> ToString[r] <> ".png", 
  Rasterize[Style[x^2 + y^2, 40], Background -> None, 
   ImageResolution -> r], 
  Background -> None], {r, {20, 40, 100, 300, 400, 500, 600}}]
```

20: [image]

40: [image]

100: [image]

300: [image]

400: [image]

500: [image]

600: [image]

---

The output that I get for the first method with the spheres appears to match the output that you get with the second method.  That is, a transparent background, but different sizes.  I will upload these outputs if requested.

Comment: So the first method in my post results in the output of the second in your machine? This is crazy. Talk about portable code.

Comment: well, I think I broke my mathematica. I tried to run a code just to try to experiment with the `ImageResolution`. First it ran fine with imageresultion of 300 then I changed to 500 and it M8 crashed. I tried again back with 300 and it crashed. Restarted my macbook pro, tried again, and it crashed. This must be a sign that I need to go to sleep. Good luck Mr.Wizard. Here is the code I was trying to run: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301676/mathematica-rasters-in-3d-graphics/6306326#6306326, oh, set in=72.

Comment: Never mind. The reason was because in the preferences I changed Antialiasing to highest quality. I changed it back to lowest and it worked. Question: Have you tried to get a transparent background with a pdf file? EDIT: Make a rasterized version of a figure and make the background transparent.

Comment: @jmlopez regarding raster with alpha in PDF, I have not tried that that I can recall.  Why don't you post that as a new question?