# Image of wire frame from 3Dgraph-can it be exported

Tags: image, 3d, wolfram-mathematica

Can a wireframe plot made with mathematica be turned into a transparent image and then exported to another site?
The reason for this question is that I am trying to fit the wireframe to a structure.

Comment: In what format do you want to  export it?

Comment: @belisarius I guess to a format that supports transparency. AFAIK that would be GIF or PNG, both supported by mma.

Comment: @Sjoerd But that does not seem what you need to `fit the wireframe to a structure`

Comment: @belisarius I assumed the OP wants to place the image as an overlay on another image of some type of structure. May be mistaken here.

Comment: @Sjoerd if you need to superimpose a wireframe to a structure you need a 3D representation, but `May be mistaken here`

Comment: This may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353337/mathematica-3d-wire-frames

Comment: If a 3D format is required, it is worth noting that not all of them will work with the example Mr.Wizard gave. DXF, WRL and X3D do, but some of the others listed in the Mathematica documentation don't for this type of `Graphics3D` object.

Answer (score 2):

The following code allows to export to GIF with transparent background (based on Mr.Wizard's code):

```
g = Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2, -x^2 - y^2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 <= 4], 
  BoxRatios -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> None, Axes -> None, 
  Boxed -> False]

Export["wireframetest.gif", g, Background -> White, 
 "TransparentColor" -> White]
```

Here is how it is displayed in the standard "[Windows Picture and Fax Viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/app_imagepreview.mspx?mfr=true)" of Windows XP:

[image: screenshot]

Note that in this case you have to specify both background for `Graphics3D` (which is `White` by default) and the color which will be converted to transparent color when exporting to GIF. So one should be careful in the case when the target image should contain non-transparent white pixels: `Export` not only completely ignores the alpha-channel of the original image but also considers equal RGB values which differ less than by 1/256.4971 (checked on 32 bit Windows XP with *Mathematica* 8.0.1):

```
Rasterize[Graphics[{RGBColor[0, 0, 0], Disk[]}]] === 
 Rasterize[Graphics[{RGBColor[0, 0, 1/256.4971], Disk[]}]]
(*=> True*)
```

One way to deal with this situation is to specify a non-standard color for the background which does not appear in the rendered version of the graphics:

```
Export["wireframetest.gif", g, 
 Background -> RGBColor[1, 1, 0.996], 
 "TransparentColor" -> RGBColor[1, 1, 0.996]]
```

This approach can be automatized. First of all, we can get all the colors which appear in the rendered version of the image:

```
neededColors = Union[Flatten[Rasterize[g, "Data"], 1]]
```

At the second step we should select a color which does not appear in this list (the following is a quick and dirty solution):

```
colorForBackground = 
 RGBColor @@ (First@
     Complement[Permutations[Range[0, 255], {3}], neededColors]/255)
```

Now we can use it as follows:

```
Export["wireframetest.gif", g, Background -> colorForBackground, 
 "TransparentColor" -> colorForBackground]
```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I am amazed that *Mathematica* is limited to 256 colors for each of the RGB channels! It is not what I expected from such comprehensive system. :(

Comment: I thought it could natively handle floating-point image data.  Let me see what I can find. --- EDIT:  yes, it seems it can.  Do you mean something else?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard What is the minimal difference? I will make a separate question if you wish.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `Image[RandomInteger[{0, 65535}, {50, 50, 3}], "Bit16", 
 ImageSize -> 200]` i.e. 16-bit color?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I am interested in the minimal difference in RGB color values which *Mathematica* renders and exports as different colors. One example: `Rasterize[Graphics[{RGBColor[0, 0, 0], Disk[]}]] === 
Rasterize[Graphics[{RGBColor[0, 0, 1/256.4971], Disk[]}]]` gives `True` on my system.

Comment: I am sorry, I misunderstood.  I think the graphics in the FrontEnd are rendered in whatever your computer is set for, which as far as I know is still limited to 8-bit/channel for normal systems.  I think this would make a good question to post.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have created [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780327/what-is-the-minimal-difference-in-rgb-color-values-which-mathematica-renders-and) on it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain I understand your requirements, but this may be adequate.

The critical bits are `PlotStyle -> None` and `Background -> None`.

```
g = Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2, -x^2 - y^2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 <= 4], 
  BoxRatios -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> None, Axes -> None, Boxed -> False]

Export["wireframetest.png", g, Background -> None]
```

[image]

You could also export as GIF, but this doesn't actually show the background as transparent. You have to set the white background as the transparent color in a graphics editor. (This was tested on Mac OS X.)

Comment: `Export` to PNG [has no option `Background`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/PNG.html) - this is why it does not work. See my answer for a solution.

Comment: @Alexey, pardon me, what doesn't work?  What version are you using?

Comment: @Alexey, I just confirmed, it works as expected on my system.  Without `Background -> None` the object is opaque; with it, it is transparent.

Comment: I apologize. I read the answer carelessly and thought that the note "but this doesn't actually show the background as transparent" is related to both PNG and GIF export. I have not checked myself. At the same time, I do not know where the option `Background` is documented for `Export` and thought that it was a mistake to use it. I have deleted my answer. +1 for this catch. But where is it documented that `Background` should work for `Export`?

Comment: @Alexey, that's okay.  For what it's worth, that was part of Verbeia's edit.  I cannot recall if it is documented, but this was shown in a post on MathGroup, and I made a note of it.  I believe the form that you posted was shown here (by you?) for a solution to other export requirements (GIF perhaps?), but I usually use the simpler one, and I prefer PNG because it supports full Alpha channel transparency.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that [GIF supports only fully transparent pixels but not semi-transparent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format#Palettes). You gave me the key: `Export` has separate option `"TransparentColor"` for specifying transparent color in the GIF palette. See new version of my answer.