# What is the minimal difference in RGB color values which Mathematica renders and exports as different colors?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, rendering, mathematica-8, mathematica-frontend

I was amazed when [I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760143/image-of-wire-frame-from-3dgraph-can-it-be-exported/7776366#7776366) that *Mathematica* gives `True` for the following code (on 32 bit Windows XP with *Mathematica* 8.0.1):

```
Rasterize[Graphics[{RGBColor[0, 0, 0], Disk[]}]] === 
 Rasterize[Graphics[{RGBColor[0, 0, 1/257], Disk[]}]]
```

What is the minimal difference in RGB color values which Mathematica renders and exports as different colors? Is it machine-dependent?

Comment: I get `False` on Mathematica 8.0.1 on Mac OS X 10.6 32-bit

Comment: @yoda Please try `1/258`, `1/259`, `1/260` and so on. What is the minimal difference on your system?

Comment: `True` In Mma 8.0 WinXP. I guess 256 distinguishable values ...

Comment: @yoda does the Mac use something beyond "32-bit" (8 bits per channel) color?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov `1/511` is when it hits `True`

Comment: @yoda Thank you! So it is OS- or machine-dependent. It is interesting to clear-up this behavior. How is it when you `Export` to PNG? Do such files identical?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I believe it's 32-bit (8/color channel + 8 for alpha).

Comment: Maybe `1/511` because of just rounding to the closest `/256`?

Comment: And this rounding occures in `Rasterize` I think.

Comment: @Nakilon That is correct. The rounding difference is exactly `1/255` as I've shown in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this behaviour is machine dependent, but I do not know how exactly it depends on the OS. On my machine, it evaluates to `True` only when the denominator is `511`.

```
n = 257; 
While[(Rasterize[Graphics[{RGBColor[0, 0, 0], Disk[]}]] === 
    Rasterize[Graphics[{RGBColor[0, 0, 1/n], Disk[]}]]) != True, 
 n++]; 
Print@n

Out[1]=511
```

There is a difference between the two images for `n<511`

```
p1 = ImageData@Rasterize[Graphics[{RGBColor[0, 0, 0], Disk[]}]];
p2 = ImageData@Rasterize[Graphics[{RGBColor[0, 0, 1/257], Disk[]}]];
ArrayPlot[p1 - p2]
```

[image]

This difference is constant all the way through `n=510` and is equal to `1/255`.

```
Max[p2 - p1] === N[1/255]
Out[1]=True
```

Comment: It is also interesting to compare a set of rectangles of different colors as they are shown on-screen (by taking a screenshot with the `PrtSc` key). Probably the results will be the same as with `Rasterize` - just for the check. For example: `Graphics[{RGBColor[0,0,#],Rectangle[]},ImageSize->40]&/@{0,1/256,1/257,1/510,1/511}`. Please post the screenshot saved in PNG format. On my machine only the second rectangle has RGB value {0,0,1} - others have {0,0,0}.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Here's what I get: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mCCoc.png It's interesting how you get `{0,0,1}`...

Comment: In your screenshot rectangles have RGB value {0,0,0} for the first and the last rectangles but for others it has RGB value {0,0,1}. I get it with Adobe Photoshop CS4. It is as expected from your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Oh, you mean RGB value of `{0,0,1/255}`. That is correct, and is what I mentioned in the answer. I was very surprised when you said `{0,0,1}`, because that's `Blue` (I understand now that you were giving the 8-bit value)...

Answer (score 3):

Looks like `Rasterize` rounds each pixel's R G B channels to the closest 8bit value (to the closest `1/256`).

```
image = Image[{{{0, 0, .2/256}, {0, 0, .7/256}, {0, 0, 1.2/256}, {0, 
     0, 1.7/256}}}, ImageSize -> 4]
ImageData@image
Rasterize@image
ImageData@Rasterize@image
```

[image]

So the *minimal difference, rasterizing into different colors* should be around 0.000000000000000000000000000...

Answer (score 1):

Guilty party here is Rasterize, which chops off color precision. Get help on `ImageType[]` to see that Mathematica actually recognizes other bit depths, but Rasterize[] vandalizes anything beyond Byte.