# Retrieving automatically-generated plot range

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is it possible to retrieve an automatically-generated plot range in Mathematica?

For example, if I were to do:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

then I'd like to know that the range of the Y axis was -1 to 1 and the range of the X axis was 0 to 2 pi.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
p = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotRange -> Automatic];
```

`AbsoluteOptions` is a bit of a lottery but works in this case

```
AbsoluteOptions[p, PlotRange]
{PlotRange -> {{0., 6.28319}, {-1., 1.}}}
```

Even though `AbsoluteOptions` superceded `FullOptions` sometimes it is also worth trying `FullOptions` if and when `AbsoluteOptions` fails because I have come across cases when `AbsoluteOptions` fails but `FullOptions` works. In this case `FullOptions`  also works:

```
FullOptions[p, PlotRange]
{{0., 6.28319}, {-1., 1.}}
```

Comment: Bingo! That's a more complete answer than I just gave above.

Comment: What's your opinion on simply pattern-matching `PlotRange` in the `FullForm` of `p`? I have had trouble with `AbsoluteOptions` in the past (perhaps due to not understanding how it works), so I now tend to avoid using it in favour of brute-force pattern-matching as in my answer.

Comment: `AbsoluteOptions` is badly broken (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717608/how-to-decrease-file-size-of-exported-plots-while-keeping-labels-sharp/8723264#comment10903578_8723264) but in principle it provides a concise why of retrieving these values. So when it works I use it and when it doesn't, after first trying `FullOptions`, then I use some sort of pattern matching routine. But it is generally the first thing I try.

Comment: @Mike OK thanks. That's what I found too, so I simply don't use it any more. It would be useful if it always worked.

Answer (score 3):

Not pretty or general, but you can brute-force it likes this:

```
p = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotRange -> Automatic];
First@Cases[p, List[___, Rule[PlotRange, x_], ___] -> x]
```

giving

```
{{0., 6.28319}, {-1., 1.}}
```

You can work this out by looking at `FullForm[p]`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `AbsoluteOptions` function, q. v. in the docs.

```
In[56]:= x = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> Automatic];
         AbsoluteOptions[x, PlotRange]

Out[57]= {PlotRange -> {{0., 6.28319}, {-1., 1.}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest the following `Ticks` hack:

```
pl = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}];
Reap[Rasterize[Show[pl, Ticks -> {Sow[{##}] &, Sow[{##}] &}], 
   ImageResolution -> 1]][[2, 1]]

=> {{-0.208333, 10.2083}, {-1.04167, 1.04167}}
```

The trick is that real `PlotRange` is determined by the FrontEnd, not by the Kernel. So we must force the FrontEnd to render the graphics in order to get tick functions evaluated. This hack gives the complete `PlotRange` with explicit value of `PlotRangePadding` added.

More general solution taking into account a possibility that `pl` has non-standard value of `DisplayFinction` option and that it may have `Axes` option set to `False`:

```
completePlotRange[plot_] := 
 Last@Last@
   Reap[Rasterize[
     Show[plot, Ticks -> (Sow[{##}] &), Axes -> True, 
      DisplayFunction -> Identity], ImageResolution -> 1]]
```

---

On the Documentation page for `PlotRange` under the "More information" one can read an important note about `AbsoluteOptions`: "`AbsoluteOptions` gives the explicit form of `PlotRange` specifications **when `Automatic` settings are given**" (highlighting is mine). So it seems that the Documentation does not guarantee that `AbsoluteOptions` will give correct values for `PlotRange` when it is not `Automatic` for all coordinates.

Comment: Hi Alexey, most of us are mainly active on the new site now, see here:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/  It'd be great if you could join too!

Answer (score 1):

Like acl I often dig into the FullForm with Position to post-process graphics:

E.g. Finding and modifying PlotRange:

```
p = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> Automatic];
rpos = Position[p, PlotRange];
Print["Initial PlotRange"];
p[[Sequence @@ Most[First[rpos]]]]
Print["Modified PlotRange"];
p[[Sequence @@ Most[First[rpos]]]] = PlotRange -> {{0, Pi}, {-1, 1}}
Print[p]
```

Or, modifying colours:

```
p = Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> Automatic];
hpos = Position[p, Hue];
Print["Initial colours"]
p[[Sequence @@ Most[#]]] & /@ hpos
Print["New colours"]
MapThread[(p[[Sequence @@ Most[#1]]] = #2) &, {hpos, {Green, Orange}}]
Print[p]
```